# Switching from On to Off (Displaying Alert) and from Off to On (Not Displaying Alert) in Toggle Button

Tags: javascript

I have Toggle Switch button and i want make it when its go from On to Off displaying a Confirm alert("Are you sure , you want to trun off status!") and when its going from Off to On it should not display Confirm alert.

I did as below but when its goes from Off to On it will displaying alert again  :) 
Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction!
Thanks in advance:)

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.switchOnOff').click(function() {

        var Id = $(this).data('id');
        var checkStatus = $(this).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked') ? 'On' : 'Off';

        if (checkStatus == "Off") {
            if (confirm("Are you sure , you want to trun off status!")) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateNtf", "Account")',
                    data: {
                        id: Id,
                        status: checkStatus
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(result) {

                        if (result) {

                            console.log("Ok");
                        } else {

                            console.log("error");
                        }

                    },
                    error: function() {
                        console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                    }
                })

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

View:

```
      @if (rma.NTFonoff == "On")
        {
         <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" checked>
         <span data-on="On" data-off="Off" class="switch-label"></span>
       }
     else 

      {
       <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input">
       <span data-off="Off" data-on="On" class="switch-label"></span>
      }
```

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ahqosb3v/

Comment: Show us your HTML. I suspect that your `checkStatus` always returns `Off` because your lookup might be incorrect. This means it will always pass the `checkStatus == "Off"` which will trigger the popup.

Comment: @vlaz i update my question

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample code which does what you asked for. I'm not going to edit you code because there's a lot of additional clutter in it which is unrelated to your question.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button')

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (this.innerText == 'On') {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      this.innerText = 'Off'
    }
  } else {
    this.innerText = 'On'
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="button">Off</button>
```

Comment: your example its useful and its working , but when i try to match up with my code it will display alert again. would you please give an example with my code .. otherwise thanks for good exampl